# How to compile modules with Swift 2.3 and 3.0?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I updated to Xcode 8 and converted to latest Swift 3.0 syntax. I have a number Cocoapods in my project, and some are on Swift 2.3 (e.g. some older pods require Alamofire set to v3.5, which runs Swift 2.3).

I have set these Pods to Use Legacy Swift -> Yes, but when building I get the error:

```
Module complied with Swift 2.3 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0: /Users/....XSDK/XSDK.framework/swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule
```

I don't use Carthage (referenced in other questions). Only Cocoapods.

Do I need to convert my project to use Swift 2.3? Or can I use Swift 3.0 in my project and still use legacy Cocoapods?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having this issue as well. Seems that you can not compile it, The owner of the code must compile it and push it out again. The pod I was trying to install pushed one out on there website but not yet to cocoa pods.

Comment: Swift is not yet ABI stable, i.e. it is not binary compatible. You cannot mix frameworks written in Swift 2.3 with apps or other frameworks that use Swift 3 (or any other version of Swift for that matter until the ABI is stable).

Comment: @hegranes did you find any solution of this issue?

Comment: @KirtiParghi -- Yes, sort of. I'll add an answer with some samples.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately as Swift is not ABI Stable, you cannot combine pods like this. The reason for this is that theres the huge swift standard library that all swift pods (and frameworks, dylibs, .a, .o, etc) need to reference once compiled. the standard library is language level dependent, and you cannot include multiple copies of the swift standard libraries in a single app.

It has been a good couple months since swift 3 was released. At this point, you're probably going to want to make the jump to 3. If you find a pod that hasn't been updated to swift 3, perhaps fork it and update it and submit a pr. The author will love you! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to follow to get legacy cocoapods working in your project.

1) Research the cocoapod and make sure you are installing the correct version of the cocoapod, which may not be the latest, or may be on a separate branch, for example.

```
$pod 'Your Cocoapod', :git => 'https://github.com/.....', :branch => 'branch_name'
```

2) Within the podfile, set the Swift version. You can also do this manually in the build settings of each pod, but this code sets it automatically.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3' # or '3.0'
      #config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```